# Can anyone explain this matlab code to me?

Tags: matlab, loops, math

```
for m = 60:70;                     %for m's values in the range of 60<m<70%;
    n((m-59))=m;                   %create an array of m's values and store the array under n
    y1((m-59)) = (14*35)/(m*9.8);  %for m's current value, calculate y1
    y2((m-59)) = 1-exp((-14*7)/m); %for m's current value, calculate y2
```

In this piece of code, what is the below line achieving?

```
n((m-59))=m;
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: `n((m-59))=m` means assign value `m` to values in `n` that are equal `m-59`, i.e. add 60 to values equal `m-59`. Together with for loop `for m = 60:70`, it adds 60 to all values in `n` that are between 1 and 10.

Comment: Not to " values in `n` that are _equal_ `m-59`", but to the _entry_ of `n` with index given by `m-59`

Answer (score 4):

This peace of code calculates `n, y1, y2` in the loop. This strange indexing used for assigning values to `n(1), n(2)` and so on: we start loop from `m=60`, so to put result in `n(1)` instead of `n(60)` it use `n(m-59)`.

Really you can avoid using loops:

```
n = [60:70];
y1 = (14*35)./(n.*9.8);
y2 = 1-exp((-14*7)./n);
```